# An incremental or another full backup?

Tags: rsync, backup

After using `rsync` to backup a file system, if there has been dramatic change in the file system since the last backup, is it still good to do an incremental backup? Is there a rule of thumb about how big a change is for a full backup to be a better choice than an incremental backup?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already experienced a system crash where you needed to restore the working filesystem from a backup? I'd propose you setup a reference system and then draw the plug. Depending on your amount of data you then can decide, if you need daily, weekly or monthly full backups.